# Support 2 base URL's in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

Is it possible to support 2 base URL's, */test/app* and */app* with the Vue router? The http requests also have to use the updated path for API calls.

Maybe it's possible to do this with aliases in vue router. But this doesn't solve the API call problem for vue resource. And this would mean I have to create 2 paths for every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, just so that you're aware, [Vue-Resource has been deprecated from official recommendation status](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4) because they don't perceive Ajax as a functionality that requires deep integration with the Vue ecosystem.

Now, to the larger question. It sounds like you're trying to use different urls based on which environment you're in (ie. local development vs. production). The easiest way to do this would be to go to the file where you define your Vue-Resource root url and add the following:

```
var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
var rootUrl = (isProduction) ? 'http://production.domain/api' : 'http://localhost:8080/api'
Vue.http.options.root = rootUrl;
```

This code basically tests if you're in production and, if you are, assigns the production domain api to the variable, otherwise it assigns the local development domain api.

[EDIT]
I took for granted that you would be using the Vue-CLI which sets this up for you. If you are using NPM to start your Vue server, you're probably running a command like `npm run dev`, which references this line in your `package.json`:

```
{
// ...
     "scripts": {
         "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
// ...
}
```

You can change that "dev" line to something like this:

```
{
// ...
     "scripts": {
         "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev node build/dev-server.js",
// ...
}
```

And that will create the NODE_ENV variable with your Node script which should allow you to use it now within the Vue context.

Comment: The line process.env returns an empty object inside my main.js file. However this is being set by the cross-env command.

Comment: @Kether Satumius How to use for different base url rather than prod or dev. For me login base url is different from other url. Please suggest how to acheive this.

Comment: @krrr25 you can customize as you need, the first code block is showing how you read the variable that is being set by the node script (3rd code block). You could even set multiple variables if need be. The NODE_ENV=dev is setting a variable, so you could just duplicate that pattern and then use the new variable in your main script. Further reading on environment variables with Node: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html